# name of the attached image (wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, post, blogs

If possible, kindly tell what is the name of the item attached in the image (e.g. Excerpt, post summary or anything else) in wordpress .. The purpose of knowing the name is so that the appropriate term can be searched on the internet.

if possible, also kindly tell that how can this be achieved via plugin or programming . (showing posts belonging to certain  category on a certain page..

Regards,[image: kindly tell the name of the item in wordpress]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image has many terms , it can be refereed to as the_post_thumbnail , an attachment, an image type attachment , a thumbnail ,featured image . etc depending on context .

But I think that the term you are searching for is [the_post_thumbnail()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail) and [Featured_image](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Thumbnails)